# How to achieve cross browser Font Uniformity with CSS?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Objective: A text with 6 text-shadow values to be shown same across Chrome, Safari, FF and preferably, IE (new) versions.

The code I am using is:

```
font-size: 2em;
color: #fff;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
text-shadow: -1px 0px 1px #000, 0px -1px 1px #000, 0px 1px 1px #000, 1px 0px 1px #000, 1px 2px 1px #000, 2px 1px 1px #000;
```

On a Mac with Chrome and Safari, it doesn't look the same since Safari shows the text "bolder".

What should I do in order to achieve cross-browser uniformity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have visual uniformity of fonts in different browsers is, well.. images.
Browsers render differently CSS decorations, not only for fonts, but also borders for example. http://www.impressivewebs.com/comparison-css-border-style/
http://css-tricks.com/font-rendering-differences-firefox-vs-ie-vs-safari/

Safari has a reputation of rendering differently fonts.